# How to create a histogram for every column in a data set on a separate page

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a single pdf that will have a frequency histogram for every column in my data set, but each histogram will be on a separate page.

I can use the code below to create a histogram for each column, but it posts it all onto one page. Is there a way to get each page separate, convert them to a pdf, then place them all in one file?

```
ggplot(gather(df), aes(value))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 4)+
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')
```

The finished product would be one PDF file containing 300+ (1 for every column) histograms.

EDIT 1:

For this code

```
df <- data.frame(
  X = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Y = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Z = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I would want 3 separate histograms in 1 pdf.

Comment: Please add data for a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the `pdf()` function then use a for loop to iterate over each column:

```
pdf('plots.pdf')
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = df[,i]), bins = 4)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: That *should* post each histogram to a page, though I can't test as writing on a phone

Comment: Hey, I tried running this iteration but the pdf file made has no pages. I replaced the df with my data set, was i supposed to change any other variables?

Comment: Edited the original thread with basic reproducible data, i think. I apologize, i'm new to r and stack overflow

Comment: Added the print function into the for loop and it worked. ty so much! Would you happen to know how to make the x axis named after the actual variable instead of  df[,i]?

Comment: `+ labs(x = colnames(df)[i])` maybe